# How to read rewritten url from an asp.net web page?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Most of the resources on the Internet seems to discuss how to do url rewriting in asp.net. None of them seem to discuss about how to read the rewritten url.

For example, I have rewritten:

```
http://www.test.com/users.aspx?id=12&name=sangam
```

to

```
http://www.test.com/profile/12/sangam.aspx
```

Now in the same page, at some point, I want to get this rewrittern url for the purpose of pointing return url in login link. Now a login link should be:

```
http://www.test.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/profile/12/sangam.aspx
```

What is the proper way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Request.RawUrl